# Boolean intersect behaves sometimes unpredictably

Tags: modifiers

I'm having some weird and mostly unreproducable error concerning the boolean-intersect modifier. In rare cases, it does not cut objA along the edge of objB but rather along the contour. See the following pictures for clearification:
[image: boolean-intersect goes wrong in forefoot part]

The modifier on the heel behaves as expected when intersecting the plane, but the one on the forefoot sometimes yields these strange results.

[image]

Does someone have an idea why that behaviour occurs? Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22/how-do-i-do-a-clean-boolean

Answer (score -1):

I tried the same, using plane for boolean operation and I got the same issue so I tried using a Cube for the Boolean rather than using a plan and there it is , solved! So you might have to use the cube for such operations and after you apply the boolean simply delete the Cube.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please take a look at the [top questions and answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions) and the amount of information they content, then please [modify](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/137301/edit) your answer so it contains enough information to help people without without further inquiries.